# Repro implementation in android

Tags: java, android

it will be very helpful if someone can provide information about how to implement and use repro in android?what are those

Repro.setup("application token");

```
    // Call the following methods to use Repro's features; they can be called in any desirable place within the app.

    // Start Recording
    Repro.startRecording();

    // Set User ID
  Repro.setUserID("foo@example.com");

   // Track Event
     Repro.track("App Launch", null);
```

Comment: What's a repro? Does it have a website? There is probably explanation on there.

Comment: its a analytic tool....http://docs.repro.io/en/quickstart/android.html @zapl

Comment: And what is it that you want to know that isn't in the documentation: http://docs.repro.io/en/api/recording.html#startrecording ?

Comment: it shows me some error,cannot  resolve repro,and also can not see in the dashboard anthing..@zapl

Comment: `it` = android studio? Did you add the `compile 'io.repro:repro-android-sdk:0.10.1'` depedency like described?

Comment: yes i do,i include the maven repository too..